# How can I add LevelHelper template on xcode?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode-template

Currently I am using xCode 3.2.5 and I have already installed cocos2d template "cocos2d 1.0.1" but and I am trying to install levelHelper Templates as per  [instruction](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6929/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-levelhelper-spritehelper-part-1) but I am unable to get level helper templates in XCode. Can you please tell what will be the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LevelHelper templates are available for only xcode 4.